# Function in .lib is defined but when i generate .so from same .lib the function is not present

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb

I have a lib1.lib which has function fun1() which shows defined when i do nm.
I have created my.so out of my.lib. But when i search my.so That fun1() is not there at all.since there might be no callers compiler might be ignoring it.
So i created some dummy array like

```
char* dummyArray={
 &fun1;
};
```

in the file where fun1() is defined.
But this also does not work.
Kindly help.

Comment: In your example, `fun1` is a [pointer to a] char, not a pointer to a function. This identifier will have no collission with an identifier in a library. However, the compiler will complain about `fun1` being undefined, so please turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: when i do nm on lib1.lib i can see the symbole is defined but why is it when i generate .so out of it the symbol not there at all??

Comment: Because you do not use a _function_ called `fun1` (you only use a _char_ called `fun1`), the linker will not fetch the function it from the library.

Comment: will try the same with void*

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The type will only be relevant in case of C++ due to name mangling (and I doubt that's the OPs problem).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ differ between Linking with .o and with .a file: different behavior, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364698/c-differ-between-linking-with-o-and-with-a-file-different-behavior-why)

Comment: @yugr, I believe there will be a mentioning of an unresolved external `fun1` of type char in the object file. The linker will search for that, also in libraries, but it will not resolve it with (load) a _function_ `fun1`.

Comment: I just found that none of the symbols in .lib are there in .so,how ever when i am trying to create an .exe its there...Is it some thing wrong with .libs?will i need to recompile the .libs to be compatible to generate .so out of it??

Comment: Is there any compiler option to make compiler not to ignore functions that are not called??

Answer (score 1):

You need to force the compiler and linker to fetch the function from the library. In your current attempt, you reference a character called `fun1` in your program. Because your `fun1` is a char, the compiler has no reason to declare a symbol in your .o file that is a function called `fun1`. As a result, function `fun1` will not be fetched from the library and there is no function `fun1` in your executable.

(Note that in your example, there is no `char fun1` declared, so your compiler should complain. Did you turn warnings on???)

To force the compiler and linker to load the function `fun1` from the library, you can write:

```
char *fun1(void);    // prototype;

char *(*p)(void)     // p is a pointer to a function with same signature as fun1...
     = fun1;         // and we initialize it with function 'fun1'
```

Note: should the compiler determine that you never use `p`, it still may remove the function pointer variable and the assignment of `fun1` to it, so `fun1` would still not have been loaded.

Comment: Is there any compiler option to make compiler not to ignore functions that are not called??

Comment: The solution I gave you, if `p` is declared as a global or static variable, will ensure the function gets loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap

```
-Wl,--whole-archive -lyourlib -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

when linking .so. For background see [c-differ-between-linking-with-o-and-with-a-file-different-behavior-why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364698/c-differ-between-linking-with-o-and-with-a-file-different-behavior-why)